# proof involving field

Tags: linear-algebra

let $A$ and $B$ be elements of a field, and suppose that $AB=0$. Prove that at least one of $A$ and $B$ must be equal to $0$.
Here is my answer: 
$AB=0$,
$AB=A.0$,
$AB-A.0=0$,
$A(B-0)=0$,
hence either $A=0$ or $B-0=0$, $B=0$.
Is this right or does too trivial for a 3 marks question?

Comment: How did you come to $A.C=0\implies A=0\vee C=0$ for $C=B-0$? If this works then you could apply it immediately on $A.B=0$.

Comment: so i used what i had to prove. wrong method then i guess. could you hint me the right way please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:

Let it be that $AB=0$ in a field. If $A\neq0$ then $A$ is a unit. So $B=1B=A^{-1}AB=\cdots$

Comment: B=A-1 AB = A-1 * 0 = 0.

Comment: Exactly. So $A\neq0\implies B=0$ or equivalently $A=0\vee B=0$

Comment: thanks for the quick reply

Comment: Glad to help. You are welcome.